# Can "it reads: " be followed by large amount of text?

Tags: phrase-requests

There's no such rules in dictionaries, but when someone uses "it reads: xxx", it's usually something short, for instance a sign, a tooltip, or a notice.

Can I use it to introduce longer text? For instance, when I'm discussing some documents with a coworker over the phone, I'm tempted to say:

> Page 42 reads: (blah blah)

> The last 2 paragraphs read: (blah blah)

If I shouldn't say "it reads" here, what should I say instead?

Comment: Why not? One of Oxford's definitions of _read_ is "(of a _passage_, text, or sign) have a certain wording" (my italics).

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin thanks, I don't think so, edited my question to mention tooltip.